# python datetime - read a time interval/range from csv formatted as HH:MM-HH:MM

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

is there a readily-available command in Python's *datetime* to understand a discrete time range given as HH:MM-HH:MM or HH:MM:ss-HH:MM:ss (e.g. 07:30-12:45)? Such a range would be entered like that in a single cell from a CSV file that the script would access.

Or, might specifying just the start time and then a *timedelta* value be a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `split()` to separate the two time values, then parse each as a `datetime.datetime` type and then calculate the `timedelta`.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime
time_string = "07:30-12:45"
separate_times = time_string.split("-")
parsed_times = [datetime.strptime(t, "%H:%M") for t in separate_times]
difference = parsed_times[1] - parsed_times[0]
```

Calling `difference.total_seconds()` will return the total seconds between the two times and if you aren't interested in the direction of the difference between the times, you can use `abs(difference.total_seconds())`.

Comment: Looks straightforward. Thank you!